# Keep getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." when copying string

Tags: c#

```
int PlayerAmount = 10;
int CurrentPlayer = 0;
Player[] player = new Player[PlayerAmount];

while (true)
{
    string Input;
    Console.WriteLine("What would you like to do?");
    Console.WriteLine("1. Create new player and score.");
    Console.WriteLine("2. Display Highscores.");
    Console.WriteLine("3. Write out to XML file.");
    Console.Write("Input Number: ");
    Input = Console.ReadLine();
    if (Input == "1")
    {
        if (CurrentPlayer >= PlayerAmount)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("MAX AMOUNT OF PLAYERS HAS BEEN REACHED!");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        else
        {
            string PlayerName;
            string Score;

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("-=CREATE NEW PLAYER=-");
            Console.Write("Player name: ");
            PlayerName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Player score: ");
            Score = Console.ReadLine();

            //=========================================
            //THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS===========
            //=========================================
            player[CurrentPlayer].Name = PlayerName;


            Console.WriteLine("Player \"" + player[CurrentPlayer].Name + "\" with the score of \"" + player[CurrentPlayer].Score + "\" has been created successfully!" );
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
    else if (Input == "2")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Displaying the highscores");
    }
    else if (Input == "3")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Writing to XML file");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("INVALID INPUT");
    }
}
```

I've already tried to use string copy but that just gives me the same error, i've already pointed the problem out in the code, but if you can't see it its where the player name is being copied: "player[CurrentPlayer].Name = PlayerName;"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't initialize each member of the `Player` array. After doing:

```
Player[] player = new Player[PlayerAmount];
```

you may want to do this as well:

```
for (int i = 0; i < PlayerAmount; i++)
{
    Player[i] = new Player();
}
```

Because beforehand, the array contains a bunch of `null` references only.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like:

```
player[CurrentPlayer].Name
```

is null.  Make sure the player object at the index of `currentPlayer` isn't null.

When you initialize an array, all objects are null (non-primitives) by default.  So you must instantiate each player per index in the array.

This line:

```
Player[] player = new Player[PlayerAmount];
```

only allocates an array of size `playerAmount` (10 in your case);

you need this to initialize them:

```
for(int i =0; i < player.length;i++)  
{  
     player[i] = new Player();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can make lazy-like thing as

```
player[CurrentPlayer] = new Player();
player[CurrentPlayer].Name = PlayerName;
```